# Display of cups in triangle/pyramid

Tags: triangles

[image: Cup stacks]

In this above picture, there are 15 cups, to make a perfect pyramid, you start the bottom row with 5 cups.

What is the formulae to start the bottom row, if I have $n$ cups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the other way round. If the base has $k$ cups, the total number of cups $n$ will be given by:

$$n=k+(k-1)+(k-2)+\ldots+1=\frac{k^2+k}{2}$$
Or:
$$k^2+k-2n=0$$
Now, just solve the quadratic equation to get:
$$k=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$
Only one of these solution will be positive, and of course, only certain $n$ will have integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

first you must find the explicit formula that gives you the number of cups in a row by plugging in the row number... first we find our difference since this pyramid starts with 5 then goes to 4,3,2,1... we know our difference or d=-1
and that row 1 or r[1] = 5
r[0]= r[1]-d = 5--1 = 5+1 = 6

r[n]= d(n)+r[0]

r[n]= -1(n)+6 <--Explicit Formula

now we put the formula in summation form: r= number of rows
$$\sum_{n=1}^r = -1(n)+6 $$

plug into calculator and it should give you the number of cups.

So...
$$\sum_{n=1}^5 = -1(n)+6 = 15 $$

Use this equation in the calculator
$$\sum_{x=1}^5 = -1(x)+6 = 15 $$

Comment: The OP's question is not to sum the given cups, but to find the general formula for the number of cups at the bottom row. For example, how many cups will there be at the bottom row if total 55 cups are used in the pyramid?